# Idiomatic way of saying "Not fluently"?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, choix-de-mot

Sometimes people will say to me, "Oh, tu parles français?" and I'll respond "Ouais, un peu, mais pas couramment."

I've always suspected this is not idiomatic, since I'm translating literally from English ("Yes, but not fluently"), which is rarely a recipe for good results.

Is this a natural phrasing, and if not, what is better?

Comment: Personnellement, je trouve pas que ce soit pas idiomatique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a one-to-one correspondance between couramment and fluently in the context of languages (couramment is also synonyme of communément and régulièrement).

> Je parle français. Je parle couramment anglais.
>
> Parler, lire, écrire couramment. Speak, read, write fluently.
>
> Parler couramment trois langues. Speak fluently three languages.

One may use also **sans difficulté**.

> Il parle le français sans difficulté (...ou bien avec aisance).

Sources:

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couramment

https://www.littre.org/definition/couramment

Comment: *Cela est écrit couramment* and *cela est écrit d'une manière courante* are at best non idiomatic and *Il lit et parle tout courant* is incorrect.

Comment: @jlliagre : J'ai rencontré ces tournures dans un dictionnaire (android apk comportant plusieurs autres dictionnaires; vieux quand même:-)!)

Comment: Cela est écrit couramment se rencontre dans l'édition 8 du dictionnaire de l'Académie Française (1932). Tout courant se donne comme synonyme de couramment dans le dictionnaire de JF Féraud (ancien un peu:-)! 1787...)

Comment: *Cela est écrit couramment* et *Il lit et parle tout courant* ne se disent plus aujourd'hui et entraîneraient des problèmes de compréhension.

Comment: D' accord:-)! Je vais effectuer les modifications tout de suite. Merci encore !\

Comment: Et pourquoi conclure par *there is not an idiomatic substitute in French* alors que *parler couramment* traduit très bien *to speak fluently* ?

Comment: Je voulais dire qu'il n' y pas d' alternatif pour couramment:-)!

Comment: Ce disant j'ai enlevé la conclusion ambiguë (ou ambigüe:-)!)

Comment: Attention, il n'y a pas d'espace après une apostrophe, et tu voulais dire *il n'y a pas d'alternative à couramment*. Utiliser *alternative* avec ce sens est considéré comme un anglicisme, mais c'est très courant.

Comment: **Espace** : Faute de frappe ; en revanche **alternatif** au lieu d'**alternative** faute impardonnable :-)! En fait comment pourrais-je éviter l'anglicisme ici ?

Comment: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1127

Comment: Probably just semantics, but is the French use of “alternative” to mean “solution/possibilité/choix” an Anglicism or rather a French misuse of it similar to its English misuse (per traditionalists) to mean anything but [“{of two things} mutually exclusive…Some traditionalists maintain that you can only have a maximum of 2 alternatives, because the word alternative comes from Latin alter ‘other (of two)’) & that uses where there are more than 2 alternatives are wrong. {But} such uses are normal in modern standard English"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alternative)? cc: @jlliagre

Answer (score 1):

Τhis sentence is correct. Ιt is a rare case in French - English translation.
But saying

> Oui, un peu, mais pas couramment

is more polite .

Un français, comme moi, te comprendrait parfaitement avec cette phrase et te trouverait même plutôt bon ;)

Comment: Why do you say it’s rare? Isn’t it a fairly common thing to say?

Comment: What is not common is to be able to say "Ouais, un peu, mais pas couramment", and not being a fluent french speaker. By using such a familiar turn, you on the contrary express your french is very good.